# How to multi select emails in browser or Gmail app?

Tags: email, browser, gmail

I want to do something like below given question in Android, is it possible to do in browser or Gmail or any other email app?

[Is there any way to easily select multiple messages in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8182/is-there-any-way-to-easily-select-multiple-messages-in-gmail)

Comment: All I can find in Android is clicking the big letter/image beside each mail. It would be very useful to get rid of groups though. The browser is basically the same (tried chrome, dolphin and firefox). Maybe someone can find a better way though.

Comment: Just to check: are you specifically asking about selecting a *range* of messages more quickly than by clicking the checkbox on each, one at a time?

Comment: Yes, currently if I want to select 20 emails, I need to tap 20 times. On Desktop chrome, I will use shift key to do in a fraction of second. I want to similar in Android.

Answer (score 4):

Within the gMail app you can select multiple messages by using the big capital letters in front of a message.

Comment: This is definitely the best way, +1 for enlightening us.

Comment: Suppose I have 50 emails in my inbox and I want to select 10th email to 40th email, I need to tap for 30 times. If I am on PC. I would first select 10th email then pressed **Shift** then select 40th email so all 30 emails would get selected. How can I do the same in Android?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible within the gmail app for android.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Gmail** app press and hold until the email is highlighted (a tick will show where the contacts initial or photo previuosly was shown). You can then select other emails as well using the same method. The top menu bar has actions you can perform for the selected emails.

Pressing the back button undoes the selections.

This is for `Version 4.7.2` but has been around for a while (since when I don't know).

Comment: I know this solution, what if I want to select 20-30 emails, I have to tap 20-30 times, which is annoying. I want more better solution like we do in Desktop chrome with use of shift key.

Comment: @Xyroid - Check Delblanco's answer. It works exactly like a check box in a web app.